# woff font MIME type on live server error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

I have an asp.net MVC 4 website where I'm using woff font. Everything works fine when running on VS IIS. However when I uploaded the pate to 1and1 hosting (live server) I get the following:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://www.com/Content/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1

When I include this in my web.config (as some suggest) my web application stops working completely and load indefinitely.

```
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried removing the mapping before adding a new one in your web.config?

For Example:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        ...
        <staticContent>
           <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        </staticContent>
```