# Font won't get found on server for firefox

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, fonts, font-face, font-awesome

I recently started using FontAwesome and everything works perfectly on the localhost in firefox, IE and Chrome. But when I published my MVC website I got this error in firebug:

**Error:**

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - xxxx://test.webapp.ilvo/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0"fontawe...v=4.2.0

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - xxxx://test.webapp.ilvo/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0"

**My font declaration in CSS (normal):**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0')   format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'),
   url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'),
   url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-  webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Font declaration in CSS (Mo’ Bulletproofer method)**

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"), url(/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot);
  src: url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"), url(/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot) format("embedded-opentype"),
     url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"), url(/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff) format("woff"),
     url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"), url(/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),
     url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"), url(/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Both of these work local! My font is stored in the map Content/fonts. I have 2 other custom fonts which work everywhere but FontAwesome is bugging for some reason.

Need help! Thx

*** EDIT**

Surfing to xxx://test.webapp.ilvo/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff gets me the font.

** **EDIT**

I tried setting mimeTypes on the server and in my webconfig but both make no difference.

**Web.config**

```
<httpProtocol> // FONTAWESOME WOFF & TTT NOT FOUND IN FIREFOX
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-truetype" />
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype" />
</staticContent>
```

Putting this in my web config does nothing.

**Respond header:**

Access-Control-Allow-Head...    content-type

Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *

Comment: Your Mo’ Bulletproofer is missing the `/content` prefix.

Comment: @DavidG That did not fix it tho

Comment: Yep, I don't understand. He is looking in the wrong location for these 2 fonts? I can surf to xxxx://test.webapp.ilvo/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff and download the font

Comment: Please post the EXACT error message and update the question with that, also with the change I suggested.

Comment: The exact error message is in the question

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521130/google-warning-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appl/15522254#15522254

Comment: I tried it before @97ldave but it does nothing :(

Comment: Firefox has a problem with cross-domain policy, I know you have tried adding a custom header in your web.config already, maybe have a look here: http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/

Comment: Can't get it to work on any browser @97ldave

Comment: I thought you only had the issue in Firefox?

Comment: I have but when I tried ur example, with fontsquirrel. It does not work anywhere.

Comment: I understand that you tried all but can you take a look here in issues of fontawesome. I also see that they have closed the issues but still since nothing is working, I think this will give some hints for more approaches. https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/755

Comment: It all leads to the same solutions but none of them work.

Comment: I've answered this issue in a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650891/woff-font-mime-type-on-live-server-error/19042976#19042976

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. This is working for me. the only change from your code is, it should be `x-font-woff` not `font-woff`.

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working. This changes does not help :(

Comment: @mitesh this actually changed to be "application/x-font-woff"  - see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521130/google-warning-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appl/15522254#15522254

Comment: @NanouPonette also try with application/x-woff or application/octet-stream and see the result.

Comment: @mitesh Nope, nothing. I still get a error on loading the.woff and .ttf font.

Comment: @NanouPonette Try one more thing, not sure if it will work. Use font awesome css file from this URL. maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the URL of your page on which fonts are not loading? and do you have access to IIS?

Comment: That will be difficult because its a intranet application. Yes I can access the IIS server.

Comment: Look at this link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/23509636/3868293](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23509636/3868293)

Comment: Hmm tried it but no luck again. I tried about everything :/

Answer (score 0):

What i clearly can see its the mismatch of the url nothing wrong with fonts just check the URL

```
xxxx://test.webapp.ilvo/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?
```

and your original url is with /Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0'

so you need to set

```
      test.webapp.ilvo/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?
```

then it will work

Comment: I have no idea what you mean?

Comment: What he he probably means is go to the font-awesome.min.css file and change the src:url(/content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0) to src:url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0) that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I provided an answer for a similar issue in this post [woff font MIME type on live server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650891/woff-font-mime-type-on-live-server-error/19042976#19042976)

The font mime type should be `application/font-woff` not `application/x-font-woff`

Comment: Looking at your problem, It's not a MIME type issue. Remove "/Content" from your css file to become @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0')   format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'),
   url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'),
   url('/fonts/fontawesome-  webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

Answer (score 0):

The question has asked 3 year, But for me no answer true. I has been researched and known how to fixed.

Open your file: .csproj and add all font you want to display. Publish again. It'll Ok.

```
<Content Include="fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot" />
<Content Include="fonts\fontawesome-webfont.ttf" />
<Content Include="fonts\fontawesome-webfont.woff" />
<Content Include="fonts\FontAwesome.otf" />
```